# How to pass request parameter to 'default-target-url'

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am setting 'cat=1' in the hidden field in login.jsp page and was expecting it to be available on the default-target-url. Entry in spring-security.xml is,

```
<form-login login-page="/login.html" default-target-url="/index.html"
            authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed.html" />
```

and in the controller,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String cat = request.getParameter("cat");
        if (cat != null && cat.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
            return "add";
        }  
        return "redirect:/index.jsp";
    }
```

but cant get request parameter value (cat is null) so I believe it is because 'default-target-url' redirects the request (and does not forward it?). Is it the case?

If yes then is there any way I can pass parameter to the 'default-target-url'?

Answer (score 3):

I have changed implementation approach a bit. Details give below,

**spring-security.xml**

```
<form-login login-page="/login.html" authentication-success-handler-ref="feedSuccessHandler"
            authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed.html" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/loggedout.html"/>

<beans:bean id="feedSuccessHandler"
     class="main.java.com.sp.utilities.FeedSuccessHandler">
    </beans:bean>
```

**FeedSuccessHandler.java**

```
public class FeedSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        String cat = request.getParameter("cat");
        if (cat != null && cat.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/add.html");
        }else{
            SavedRequest savedRequest = new HttpSessionRequestCache().getRequest(request, response);
            if(savedRequest != null) {
                response.sendRedirect(savedRequest.getRedirectUrl());
            }else{
                response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Application is working as desired also in future if I want to customize redirection based on roles, I can use same class.

Answer (score 1):

It does *redirect* by defult, but there are a couple configuration options you can use to change this behavior. Both of them is defined on the  `AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler` which is the parent class of the two existing authentication success handler implementations (by default `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` is used by the namespace configuration).

1. Set its `targetUrlParameter` property, so that it will check if the HTTP request has a parameter with that name. If so, it will redirect to the URL given in that request parameter.
2. Or set a custom `redirectStrategy`. The default implementation calls `response.sendRedirect()`, but you can change that as you like in your custom implementation.

You will have some difficulty though, because neither of these configuration points are exposed through the namespace configuration, so you will need to go a level deeper, and write the bean definitions manually.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect is controlled by the Redirect Strategy definined in the `redirectStrategy` property of `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler`.

The Default for `redirectStrategy` is an instance of `DefaultRedirectStrategy`.

What you need to do is to implement you own  `redirectStrategy` (implements `RedirectStrategy`).
And then configure it:

```
...
<bean id="usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
    ...
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler">
        <bean
           class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
            <property name="redirectStrategy">
               <bean class="yourRedirectStrategy"/>
            <property>
         </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```